# ¿ Que pasa con las recompensas en respuestas wiki de comunidad?

Tags: discusión, recompensas

Esta pregunta: [Sincronía vs. Asincronía para recoger datos en tiempo real con javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/166250/19610) tiene actualmente una recompensa activa.

He estado escribiendo una respuesta (por qué negarlo, la recompensa es *golosa*), pero he visto que se está extendiendo **demasiado**. Entiendo las motivaciones del *benefactor*: es un tema **muy, muy referido** en multitud de preguntas con la etiqueta <kbd>JavaScript</kbd>, y una respuesta *canónica* sería perfecta: permitiría marcar como *duplicadas* una gran cantidad de preguntas futuras.

Dado lo amplio de tema por la multitud de conceptos que hay que *tocar*, me estoy planteando la posibilidad de marcar mi respuesta como `Wiki de comunidad`, lo cual permitiría:

- Usuarios con mejores conocimientos que los mios en temas concretos, puedan mejorar la respuesta.
- La respuesta se mantenga *al día* en futuras versiones del lenguaje.
- Mas usuarios colaboren en su completud: aunque sea *de pasada*, son muchos conceptos por tocar, y es fácil dejarse alguno en el tintero.

Bueno, la pregunta: suponiendo que no se publiquen nuevas respuestas, por las reglas de las recompensas, esta sería *para el menda*: respuesta con mas puntos publicada **después** de ofrecer la recompensa.

¿ Que pasa con la recompensa si la marco como `Wiki de comunidad` ? ¿ Se pierde ?

Comment: Sí, recibirás tu merecida recompensa : )

Comment: @fedorqui ¡ *Otia* ! Y mira que busque por `recompensa`, pero se me pasó la que indicas :-(